# Flash Plugins required

Tags: flash

I have recently upgraded OS to 14.10 from 14.04. I am facing issue with Flash Plug-ins. My default browser is Chromium but i am not getting suitable plug-ins for this browser.

I tried installing flash using following command but its not working.

```
sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-installer
```

This was the error code :-

```
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox
 virtualbox-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: did you tried with `apt-get install -f`

Comment: apt-get install -f o- not working
sandesh@sandesh:~$ apt-get install -f
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Answer (score 0):

I have had same problem, and you could try enter in the terminal this:

```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall pepper
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall freshplayerplugin 
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a freshplayerplugin
```

and it might work fine this way.